# Setting Images Side by Side & responsive in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have written a code where 4 images are kept inside div side by side in cols.

Below is the code :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                <img src="image2.jpg" alt="1" style="width:100%; height:70%;" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                <img src="image3.jpg" alt="1" style="width:100%; height:70%;" class="img-responsive"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                <img src="image4.jpg" alt="1" style="width:100%; height:70%;" class="img-responsive"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                <img src="image5.jpg" alt="1" style="width:100%; height:70%;" class="img-responsive"/>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

This looks like this in full size window :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERqdk.jpg)

Now when the window size is minimized, the images looks like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj5cc.png)

I want the image to look the way it looks in the full size even after minimizing without the image getting stretched.

I was able to get the view of above images without it getting stretched when i removed the style: width:100%; height:70%; but then in full sized window the images had blank spaces between each other.

Please help me to get this sorted.

Comment: Did you try `height: auto;`?

Comment: Any luck with this @James? Did my approach work on your current setup?

Comment: @FredRocha hey Fred, I tried using only img-reponsive & losing the inline styles but then the images were looking like this in full screen window size : (Check below)

Comment: The images are only going to resize to their maximum width (otherwise they'd get blurred). Make sure you use wider images, or limit your container or row.

Comment: so how do i limit the container or row ?

Answer (score 1):

Using

`class="img-responsive"`

will make your images responsive across devices. In specific, and as per [Bootstrap's documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive), it will add

```
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: block;
```

to your image elements.

You will need to lose your inline styles

```
style="width:100%; height:70%;"
```

as they override everything else (Protip: never use them).

Lastly, if you don't want the blank spaces between images you'll need to force remove the padding for each column. Example:

```
div.col-xs-3 {
    padding: 0;
}
```

[Here](http://codepen.io/fredrocha/pen/PWLROB) is a sample codepen.

Answer (score 0):

@FredRocha hey Fred, I tried using only img-reponsive & losing the inline styles but then the images were looking like this in full screen window size:

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XH9Wf.png)

Comment: Instead of adding a new answer edit your original question as you progress, @James. ;)

Answer (score -2):

Maybe adding **img-responsive** class to image will fix the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I've not seen it.